# laravel get relation table as key=>val

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Fisrt sorry for my poor english. Second I have one table of content with relation of user, meta, and more.. my contents_meta table is like this

```
---------------------------------
content_id |   option  |  value
---------------------------------
    1           price     12
---------------------------------
    2           price     14.1
---------------------------------
```

and query like this

```
$lists = Content::with([
    'categories',
    'user',
    'metas' => function($qm){
        $qm->get()->pluck('option','value');
    },
    'transactions' => function($q){
        $q->where('mode','deliver');
    }
])->withCount('sells','partsactive');
```

I use pluck to change content_meta table `key => val`

```
$item->metas->price = ???[get value]
```

But pluck not work and all of content return in array. How i can convert to `key => val` result in query?

Comment: Please describe in detail, It's difficult to understand

Comment: i want get content_meta in key=>val array like this $qm->get()->pluck('option','value'); but not working

Comment: Still your question not clear, and i didn't understand wha is your needs, but in `with` function you should write a query to get the data of relation that has your needed conditions, you cannot use `pluck`